# Desenlistar una salida de una función en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy utilizando la función `random.choices()` en el siguiente código:

```
senales=["A","B","C","D"]
probs=[0.2,0.8,0,0]
elecc = choices(senales, probs)
print(elecc)
```

Obtengo como salida datos de este tipo: `["B"]`

Qué manera práctica hay para obtener una salida no enlistada y no encadenada del tipo: `B`

Las soluciones que encuentro utilizando `intertools` son muy farragosas

Comment: Puedes poner algunos ejemplos de salidas deseadas?
Incluyendo el tipo de dato que esperas

Comment: Las que arroje el código: con las probabilidades dadas. Habrá un 20% de A y un 80% de B. No obstante lo que me interesa es encontrar una manera práctica de que la salida sea un objeto no enlistado y no encadenado.

Comment: Podrías hacer algo así: `selecc = choices(senales, probs)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solonecesitas referirte a lo que tienes dentro de la lista. Prueba esto

```
from random import choices

senales=["A","B","C","D"]
probs=[0.2,0.8,0,0]
elecc = choices(senales, probs)[0]
print(elecc)
```

Comment: es cierto... cómo no habré pensado en algo tan sencillo antes...

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza * que desempaquetar la variable:

```
 print(*elecc)
```